# Troubles with high baud rates of serial port

Tags: .net, visual-c++, serial-port, hardware

I am using Optris pyrometers of CT series. In terms of hardware, they use USB interface, and in terms of software, they use COM port communications. Before, I worked with older versions of these pyrometers, and everything was fine. But now I have a new device and my code (C++ .NET) does now work with it. Using Free USB analyzer, I see that data is sending to the device, but it does not react on any command.

What I already checked (carefully!):

1. I use right digital commands
2. I use right settings of serial port, and the port is opening
3. Both software products of the manufacturer work fine! So, the device, the cables and so on are OK
4. Optris support told me that from the point of view of a developer, nothing has changed comparing to the previous devices

The only thing that differs old devices from the new one is the baud rate. Previously, it was 9600, and now it is 115200. So it seems that the problem can be in this.

Here are also pieces of my code:

In class constructor:

```
sp = gcnew SerialPort(ComPort, 115200, Parity::None, 8, StopBits::One);
```

When I start to acquire:

```
sp->DtrEnable = true;
sp->DataReceived += gcnew SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this, &Pyrometer::OnDataReceived);
sp->BaseStream->Flush();
ThreadPool::QueueUserWorkItem(gcnew WaitCallback(this, &Pyrometer::callBack), sp);
```

In callback:

```
Thread::Sleep(500);
sp->Write(gcnew array<wchar_t> {0x52, 0x01, 0x53}, 0, 3); // Burst mode
```

I also tried greater wake up time - no results.

Does anybody know what can be the problem? I lost a lot of time on this issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a surprising solution. I changed port of the device from COM4 to COM3 (both in system and in code). And it started to work. Before, it didn't work even with stopped antiviruses and firewalls. It seems to be a bug in Windows, or I even don't know what was it. It is so weird.